# Remove Achievement from iTunes Connect Game Center

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, achievements

I first thought of having some achievements in first version of my game app. So I created one in *iTunes Connect* for test. Now I don't want to have any achievements for user. I want to delete it, but there is no delete option surprisingly. Box under status column is empty.

[image]

In [apple doc:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html)
[image]

So the Question is when can I delete achievement? What's the restriction? Please can someone tell me how can I remove achievements from itunes connect game center? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem is all about the iTunes web site. Actually, there are delete buttons on the status column but they cannot be seen. And the only reason is that the "padding" property of the column's style class.

The solution steps:

1. On achievement list; right click any of the rows and select "Inspect Element".
2. There are many of the html list item elements ("li"). Expand one of them and the div under of that.
3. Select on of the div elements that have "ajaxListColumn" class.
   On the right panel, deselect the padding property (it should be the third style).

I added a screenshot for the steps above.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: hahaha OMG. It worked!! Ihe irony is that apple has made such a stupid mistake. Really. Thanks for the help dude.

Comment: Good find, just had this same issue myself.

Comment: Got two serial rejects from Apple just because i was unable to delete unused achievements. Thanks a lot!